# Counting the numbers of linear combination

Tags: combinatorics

Let $ A $ be a set that contains numbers of the form $ 2^{i} $ where $ i \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}. $ How many distinct linear combinations $ \displaystyle \sum_{0 \le j \le 6} c_{j}2^{j} $ can we make from $ A $ such that each $ c_{j} $ is either $ 0 $ or $ 1 $ and such that each combination is less than or equal to $ 100. $

For example $ 37 = 2^{0} + 2^{2} + 2^{5} $ would be a valid linear combination. The difficulty I have so far is the restriction that the linear combination must be less than or equal to $ 100. $ I list all possible combinations and there seems to be exactly $ 100 $ combinations, but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard of the binary number system? It is like decimal but for cool kids. Basically the numbers that can be formed in the way you are asking using $2^0,2^1\dots 2^n$ are precisely $\{0,1,2,\dots ,2^{n+1}-1\}$.

Lets prove it:

The proof is by induction.

The base case is trivial, clearly the combinations of $\{1\}$ are $\{0,1\}$.

Inductive step:

We need to prove every number in $\{0,1,2\dots 2^{n+2}-1\}$ is a combination of $\{1,2\dots 2^{n+1}\}$. Let $x$ be the number we want to make:

If $x$ is in the range $\{0,1,\dots 2^{n+1}-1\}$ then we don't even need to use $2^{n+1}$ to make it (inductive step).

If $x$ is in the range $\{2^{n+1},2^n+1\dots 2^{n+2}-1\}$ then we start by adding $2^{n+1}$. Now we just need to use the remaining numbers to make $x-2^{n+1}$. Luckily this number will be in the range $\{1,2\dots 2^{n+1}-1\}$, so by the inductive hypothesis we can make it, without using $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: Cool kids club member here.  As for your answer, a slight strengthening of your induction hypothesis would be helpful for the OP's specific problem, rewording it to say "Every number in $[2^{n+2}-1]$ can be written as $\sum\limits_{0\leq j\leq n+1} c_j 2^j$ with each $c_j$ equal to either $0$ or $1$."  The body of the proof is still valid, but it was unclear that your induction hypothesis claims that we can make such a combination using only zeroes and ones as coefficients.

Comment: I feel like I've got to support this answer. Can't let down my fellow cool kids in our club!